# Solr average of function result

Tags: solr

I have a solr index with documents that have a fields `started` and `stopped` which both hold a datetime. I would like solr to output an average difference between them.

To get the difference between `started` and `stopped` I have used `diff:ms(started, stopped)` within fl.

I know you can get stats about a field with `stats=true` and `stats.field=fieldname` but if i use either `diff` or `ms(started, stopped)` as the field name it errors with an undefined field error.

So is what I want possible? If so, how do i go about it?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the function support in the [JSON Faceting API](http://yonik.com/json-facet-api/):

```
q=*:*&
json.facet={
  "avg_time": "avg(ms(started, stopped))"
}
```

Comment: I wish i could but i am unable to add any extra components and i am using solr 4.4.0 which i am also unable to change